# how do I get a click handler on an image?

Tags: apache-flex

I want to get this to work:

private function frigganWork(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
     trace("WTF?");
     navigateToURL(new URLRequest("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"), "_self");

```
}
```

but I get an error: "Call to possibly undefined method frigganWork."

Comment: In what context are you calling this method from (post more code please)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're inside a [`mx:Component`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mxml/component.html) tag, your scope has changed: `this` now refers to the itemRenderer component.

You can resolve to the larger scope by using `outerDocument`.  The event handler function does need to be public since it's being called from another class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public function onClick(event:Event):void {}
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
    <mx:ComboBox>
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:Image click="{outerDocument.onClick(event)}" />
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:ComboBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Agreed.  I've always used parentDocument, but it seems the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling frigganWork() from within an inline item renderer - you have to change the scope of the method to public.

Comment: <mx:Image  source="assets/{data.source}" buttonMode="true" click="frigganWork()"  />
I've changed the scope to public, same error

Comment: <mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
     <mx:VBox   verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
        verticalScrollPolicy="off" backgroundColor="#cccccc" rollOverEffect="bLur"  >
        <mx:Image  source="assets/{data.source}" buttonMode="true" click="frigganWork()"  />
      
     </mx:VBox>
     
    </mx:Component>
    
   </mx:itemRenderer>